# How to find all occurences of "call-time pass-by-reference" in PHP project and remove/repair them?

Tags: php, regex, pass-by-reference

Call-time pass-by-reference was deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 (2009) and it was removed as of PHP 5.4.0 (2012). But still I meet this problem on older PHP projects when migrating them to new server. How to find all occurences of "call-time pass-by-reference" in PHP project and remove/repair them?

Comment: `php -l <file>` will give you a warning or a parse error, depending on the PHP version. In either case, you'll also get a line number.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Is there a possibility to check all files in project in this way? Something like `php -l *.php`

Comment: Not with php directly, you'd just have to wrap it in a shell loop or an xargs or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this (at least I have not found any). It must be done manually. Call-time pass-by-references can be found in project files quite precisely by following regex (use your IDE to launch regex serach):

```
(?<!function)[:> ][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<!foreach|array)\s?\([^()]*&\$
```

Found occurences you must repair one by one manually. You have to:

- Remove the ampersand sign in function/method calls. E.g. something like `$myResult = myFunction(&$myVar)` you will rewrite to `$myResult = myFunction($myVar)`.
- Check if `myFunction()` is defined with first argument passed by reference like `function myFunction(&$myArg1)`. If not (it means the ampersand is missing in definition) then you must repair it and add the ampersand
- If  the ampersand was missing in the definition of `myFunction()` then you must check if all calls of `myFunction()` in project are done with "call-time pass-by-reference". If yes then you are done. If not (it means there are calls of `myFunction()` without "call-time pass-by-reference") then you must consider if it changes something if you use pass-by-reference and if yes then you should write a pas-by-value of `myFunction()` and use it for these occurences

Comment: Using a regex to do that is not a good idea, there're many cases this approach will perform inappropriate replacements. The way to do that is to write a php script that uses the tokenizer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, the [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) could be used to prepare full-automatic solution. But you have to at first develop it. I'm just looking for quick-and-dirty solution, when you are going round some old project and you have +20 minutes to make it work. Replacements are not done automatically. Programmer makes them (so he decides if they are appropriate) and the regex just narrows the amount of cases to be checked. Provided regex is not bulletproof probably, but quite well doing its job :)

Comment: The following version takes care of some additional edge cases: `(?<!function\s)\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<!\bforeach|\barray|\buse)\s*\([^()]*&\$`